# Editing XML by Jenkins + Powershell Remote

Tags: xml, powershell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

First I want to say,that it is 100% working script from Powershell ISE"
I have to remote Edit XML file through Jenkins Job + Powershell.

Powershell script remote editing is working well from Jenkins Windows Slave machine. But, when I'm running it with *Jenkins Environment variable + Powershell plugin* it fails. Looks like it failing to "put" string into .Load option of powershell. 
 So first , we're setting variable **XML_PATH** from Jenkins with string (for example)
`"**C:/Temp/settings.xml**"`

Second is code in powershell ,

```
$username = "domain\user"
$password = "password123"
$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr

$ScriptBlock = { 
$test = "$env:XML_PATH"
$xml = New-Object XML
$xml.Load($test)
$SiteRoot =  $xml.SelectSingleNode("//SiteRoot")
$SiteRoot.InnerText = "www.hellokitty.com:8080"
$appUrl = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//SiteUrl")
$appUrl.InnerText = "www.hellokitty.com:8080/kitty"
$xml.Save($test)
 }

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $env:SERVER_NAME -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -Credential $Cred -ArgumentList $Cred
```

So after adding variable XML_PATH  through Jenkins and adding it to the script, I'm getting an error from Jenkins Console:

```
***Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "Load" and the argument count: "1".
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
    + PSComputerName        : webserver1***
```

Any suggestions/ideas? Again.. script is working 100%... Environment Variable **$env:XML_PATH** can print correct answer too, if you're running it like this:

```
$test = "$env:XML_PATH"
Write-Host $test
```

BTW: I can see,that another Env Variable working well from Jenkins to Remote Powershell and all string parameters were read:

**$env:SERVER_NAME**

Comment: Does `$env:XML_PATH` exist in the context of the Jenkins user account? What is the exact value of that variable? Do you get the same issue with a hard-coded path?

Comment: only a string - path to XML - "C:\Temp\settings.xml"  , I believe it happens because powershell + Environment variable + Invoke-Command.. something here.. but I cant catch it.. (Powershell v2 on the destination server) P.S - $env:XML_PATH - set from Jenkins Job under Parameterized build -- as simple String Parameter

Comment: Answer the questions, please. Don't speculate. As an alternative you could try replacing `$xml = New-Object XML; $xml.Load($test)` with `[xml]$xml = Get-Content $env:XML_PATH` and see if that works.

Comment: Try typing as String the parameter of the Load method. .NET is telling you it cannot figure out which of the overload of method Load of object System.Xml.XmlDocument to use.

Comment: Ansgar, It's not working I've put this `$xml = Get-Content $env:XML_PATH` instead and got an error: `Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBinding 
   ValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,M 
   icrosoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand`

Comment: Gzeh,  hi, I'm trying to understand. Thank you. I can reproduce it without Jenkins.From Powershell ISE. Just put **$XML_PATH="C:\Temp\settings.xml"** variable before setting  *Scriptblock* so inside of scriptblock we cant read same variable, I suppose.  I'm getting same error, that I've answered to Ansgar before. With _Path is null_

Comment: Hi guys. Gzeh was right  - added into the Scriptblock : `param(
    [string]$XML_PATH
)` So I could read it as param  and it worked from Powershell ISE. But still Have issue from Jenkins.. because it's Envrionment Variable..

Comment: And finally!!! To read it from Jenkins (I have no time to test more) I did the following - before ScriptBlock added `$XML_PATH = $env:XML_PATH`  where **$XML_PATH** is  Jenkins parameter (you can create any). Thank you all! :) cya